# Ruby on Rails Change Order of Custom Model Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a form that has model validations which works properly in my local system however when i check it on live site the order of the model validations order gets changed although the code is same in both.

this is the block of code in model:

```
 def validate

    #email validation
    if !email.blank?
      #errors.add(:email,I18n.t(:ismissing))
      #else
      if email != email_confirmation
        errors.add(:email,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageConfirmEmailNotmatch))

      else
        if email.length <=200 then
          if email.match(/^[^@][\w.-]*@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i).nil?
            errors.add(:email,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageInvalid))
          else

            if @new_record==true
              if User.find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(email) = ?', email.downcase]).count>0
                #errors.add(:email," ID already exists. Provide another Email ID")
                errors.add(:email,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageAlreadyExists))
              end
            else
              if @changed_attributes["email"]!=nil
                if User.User.find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(email) = ?', email.downcase]).count>0
                  #errors.add(:email," ID already exists. Provide another Email ID")
                  errors.add(:email,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageAlreadyExists))
                end
              end
            end


          end
        else
          errors.add(:email, I18n.t(:ErroeMessageMustlessthen,:size=>200))
        end
      end
    else
      errors.add(:email,I18n.t(:ismissing))
    end
    #end : Email validation

   if email_confirmation.blank?
      errors.add(:email_confirmation,I18n.t(:ismissing))
   end

    #pasword validation
    if @new_record==true
      if password.blank?
        errors.add(:password,I18n.t(:ismissing))
      else
        if password_confirmation != password
          errors.add(:password,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageConfirmPasswordNotmatch))
        end
        if !password.nil?
          if password.length < 4 || password.length > 50 then
            errors.add(:password,I18n.t(:ErroeMessageShouldBetween,:from=>"4",:to=>"50"))

          end
          errors.add(:password,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageInvalidPassword)) if password.match('^[a-z0-9@#*-_]*$').nil?
        end
      end
    end
    #end password validation

  if @new_record==true
    if password_confirmation.blank?
      errors.add(:password_confirmation,I18n.t(:ismissing))
    end
  end

    if dob.blank?
      errors.add(:dob,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageInvalid))
    else
      begin
        #dt =   DateTime.strptime(dob, "%m/%d/%Y").to_date
        if dob.year <= 1900 then
          errors.add(:dob,I18n.t(:ErrorMessageInvalidYear))
        end
        if dob>=Date.today then
          errors.add(:dob,I18n.t(:ErroeMessageInvalidBirthday))
        end

      rescue Exception => ex
        #errors.add(:dob,'is Invalid (MM/DD/YYYY format)')
        errors.add(:dob,I18n.t(:ErroeMessageInvalidBirthday))
      end
    end

  end
```

and the controller calls the Validate method on registration.An urgent help is required If anybody has any suggestions or ideas .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: cant you use the default rails validations? why do you need your own ones? you can send a custom error message even when using the default rails validations...

Comment: Let me quote the ruby core:
`# Call this at the top of your tests when you absolutely positively need to have ordered tests. In doing so, you're admitting that you suck and your tests are weak.`
`def self.i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!`

Comment: @klump : how to use default validations for birth date and email and phone no: regular expressions , i think we have to provide custom...if not can you please explain how do i use them?

Comment: @tass : i don't get what you are trying to say....??

Comment: @user1280137: see stalin's answer down there, i would have done something like him

Answer (score 2):

You can use rails default validations..I did for email and gave you the sample here..

```
 validates :email, 
        :presence =>{ :message => I18n.t(:ismissing)},
        :length => {:allow_blank => true, :maximum => 200, :message => I18n.t(:ErroeMessageMustlessthen,:size=>200)}, 
        :format => {:allow_blank => true, :with => /^[^@][\w.-]*@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i, :message => I18n.t(:ErrorMess
        :uniqueness => {:allow_blank => true, :message => I18n.t(:ErrorMessageAlreadyExists)}, 
        :confirmation => {:message => I18n.t(:ErrorMessageConfirmEmailNotmatch)}
```

Likewise you can also do for other fields.

Comment: Hi Stalin : validation works but when i put validations for multiple fields the order in which they are displayed is still not in order...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why these wouldn't be executing in order. Have you logged something to indicate that in production?

Rather than put everything in a big validate method, maybe split into several (probably a better practice in general), then call in the order you want.

eg.

```
before_save :validate_email, :validate_dob


def validate_email
...
end

def validate_dob
...
end
```

Comment: Hello Kevin ...Validations do not get fired if i split them is there some other way to maintain their order